# Android - Scrolling text in main activity (marquee_forever) gets initialized when internal fragment changes

Tags: android, fragment, horizontal-scrolling, actionbarsherlock, ticker

I'm facing a strange problem with a "ticker" (a horizontal auto-scrolling text).

My application uses fragments. Lots of them. It's based on a single activity, with an action bar, a fragment container and a bottom ticker.

Ticker is scrolling correctly, from left to right, but every time i change fragment, my ticker gets initialized again (current horizontal scrolling is lost and it starts from the beginning again, but no-one is telling him to do that!).

I'm using actionbarsherlock (works like a charm! thank you Jake Wharton!!) for compatibility mode.

Here's some code :

MAIN ACTIVITY LAYOUT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/mainRelative" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tickerView1" >
</LinearLayout>
<my.app.views.TickerView
    android:id="@+id/tickerView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
     </my.app.views.TickerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

TICKERVIEW CLASS

```
public class TickerView extends TextView {
private Context context;

public TickerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public TickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public TickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initialize();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void initialize() {
    context = getContext();
    String s;
    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    setSingleLine();
    setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    setSelected(true);
            setText("sdghaskjghaskgjashgkasjghaksjhgaksjghakjshgkajsghaksjghaksjgh");

}
}


@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "ON FOCUS CHANGED");
    if (focused)
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "ON WINDOW FOCUS CHANGED" + (focused ? "FOCUSED" : "NOT FOCUSED"));
    if (focused)
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
}

@Override
public boolean isFocused() {
    return true;
}
```

I've also tried the xml-based solution (setting up a layout file with correct attributes for scrolling text and extending my widget from LinearLayout), but i had same results.
Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer but what version of ABS are you using? Is it 3.5 or 4? The tab text scrolls fine for me in 3.5 but I am having serious issues with it in version 4.

Have you tried `setSelected(false)`? It probably won't solve your problem but your code looks fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (i'm using ABS4), I've solved my problem without using xml marquee attribute and using a custom class with animation code instead.